# I've installed Karma, now what?

Tags: karma-runner

I've installed and implemented Karma in my project, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I have one a very simple jasmine spec just to test Karma:

```
describe 'A suite', ->
  it 'contains spec with an expectation', ->
    expect(true).toBe true
```

However, where do I go from here?

Here's how it looks when I visit it in a browser:

[image: browser screenshot]

**Where is my jasmine spec?**

Here's how my console looks:

```
rake karma:start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.28 server started at http://localhost:9876/_karma_/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Connected on socket FNsNSoQPPqyGCqhqIduv with id 80517079
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')
  at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.3.8/app/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js:26070


INFO [Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux)]: Connected on socket HbXSzzvaLb-tMVMNIduw with id manual-2655
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')
  at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.3.8/app/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js:26070


Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.3.8/app/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js:26070
```

**Again, not a hint of my spec**

Are these error messages causing a problem?

```
 Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) LOG: 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'

 Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) ERROR
      Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.3.8/app/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js:26070
```

Sorry if this is vague, but I have no idea what should happen. I'm expecting when I visit `localhost:9876/_karma_/` for all my jasmine spec(s) to show. I'm expecting similiar output in the console from PhantomJS but nothing is happening! I've got nothing to go on.

**Any** help **greatly** appreciated (Definitely be awarding a bounty) on how I display my spec(s)!

Answer (score 2):

Loading angular twice is definitely the issue here. If you have used ...**/angular.js in the files element of the karma config file, I bet there are multiple angular.js files in your project, was the case for me.... You can inspect the karma page and find the sources to see what files were loaded. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to fix an issue. Do you use coffescript processor?

You can clone https://github.com/yearofmoo/angularjs-seed-repo repo to look at proper config for Karma and Protractor test cases.

Also, you can select one of neat reporter instead of `process`. Look at **[npm repository](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=karma%20jasmine%20reporter)**

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, if you only require karma unit testing (not end to end) then you can remove the `ng-scenario` framework from the karma configuration and it should be possible to run

```
rake karma:start
```

Admittedly this doesn't solve the problem entirely but it might get you going if you are stuck.