# Running Karma using PhantomJS for Angular: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()')

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have just installed Karma to run tests on an AngularJS application. Karma starts properly, but before running any tests it comes up with the following error, using both PhantomJS and Chrome.

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) ERROR   TypeError: 'undefined' is not a
>   function (evaluating 'window.angular.$$csp()') at
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@project/gems/rails-assets-angular-1.3.14/app/assets/javascripts/angular/angular.js:26181
>
> Chrome 42.0.2311 (Mac OS X 10.10.3) ERROR   Uncaught TypeError:
>   window.angular.$$csp is not a function

I have also tried running it on Linux, but getting the exact same errors. I have tried to add the `ngCsp` directive to the application, but this does not change anything.

I have very little testing experience and as such I am not sure how to proceed. I'm not clear on whether this is an error in the Karma configuration or whether it is something in my project? How would I best tackle this?

Comment: @bluefeet When I tried voting to close it says I can't close because the alternative 'doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer', So now this question will just sit here unanswered when what is quite possibly a helpful response has been deleted by you. Brilliant.

Comment: The duplicate is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611493/ive-installed-karma-now-what/30740661#30740661